# How to explain this sentence structure

Tags: syntactic-analysis, verb-forms

> He later *admitted having seen the dish* on the menu...

Would I break down the form of this as follows:
admitted (verb, past participle of admit) + having (verb to have + -ing) + seen (verb past participle of see) + the dish (article + object)?

I feel like I'm missing something here with needing to explain "*having seen*" as present perfect, and why one can or can't use "admitted **to** having seen".

Comment: Yes, but "admittted" is not a past participle but a preterite (simple past) form. The "to" is optional.

Comment: You can admit something or admit to something. Basically, the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Subject: *he*; Predicate: the rest of it.

*later*: adverb modifying *admitted*.

*having seen the dish on the menu*: [gerund phrase](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund-phrase/) which serves as the object of verb *admitted*. "To" doesn't matter. I can admit my error, or can admit to my error.

*having seen* is the verb of its gerund phrase.

*the dish* is its object.

*on the menu is*, IMJ, a modifier of having seen. It could modify *the dish*.